# Python/Scapy Performance on embedded device using Wi-Fi

Tags: python, performance, wifi, scapy

I am using Scapy to capture Wi-Fi client request frames. I am only interested in the MAC and requested SSID address of the clients. I do something like the following.

```
sniff(iface="mon0", prn=Handler)

def Handler(pkt):
    if pkt.hasLayer(Dot11):
       if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 4:
           print pkt.addr2 + " " + pkt.info
```

My issue is that I am doing this on a embedded device with limited processing power. When I run my script, my processor utilization rises to nearly 100%. I assume this is because of the sheer volume of frames that Scapy is sniffing and passing to my Python code. I also assume that if I could employ the right filter in my sniff command, I could eliminate many of the frames that are not being used and thus reduce the processor load.

Is there a filter statement that could be used to do this?

Comment: Could you describe what you have set up on the interface and what type of environment you are operating in?

Answer (score 3):

With Scapy it is possible to sniff with an [BPF Filter](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) applied to the capture. This will filter out packets at a much lower level then your `Handler` function is doing, and should significantly improve performance.

There is a simple example in the [Scapy documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#filters).

```
# Could also add a subtype to this.
sniff(iface="mon0", prn=Handler, filter="type mgt")
```

Filter pieced together from [here specifically](http://seclists.org/tcpdump/2012/q1/63).

Unfortunately I can't test this right now, but this information should provide you with a stepping stone to your ultimate solution, or someone else to post exactly what you need. I believe you will also need to set the interface to monitor mode.

You may also find this question of interest - [Accessing 802.11 Wireless Management Frames from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214189/accessing-802-11-wireless-management-frames-from-python).

Comment: This option might work if I could get the filter to work. Your example throws a Scapy exception of "Filter parse error".

Answer (score 2):

Scapy is extremely slow due to the way it decodes the data. You may

- Use a BPF-filter on the input to only get the frames you are looking for before handing them to scapy. See [this module for example](http://code.google.com/p/pyrit/source/browse/trunk/pyrit/cpyrit/pckttools.py). The module uses libpcap to get the data from the air or from a file first and passes it through a dynamically updated BPF-filter to keep unwanted traffic out
- Write your own parser for wifi in c (which is not too hard, given the limited amount of information you need, there are things like prismhead though)
- Use tshark from wireshark as a subprocess and collect data from there

I highly recommend the third approach although wiresharek comes with a >120mb library that your embedded device might not be able to handle.